# check if an integer exists in a specific column of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I 've to do the following exercise:

Write a function that given two integers (x and k ) and a M X N matrix,
returns TRUE if there is an element that occurs at least k times
in at least x columns of the matrix.

this is my solution but there is something wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int DIM = 3;

bool check ( int matrix[DIM][DIM], int element,  int k,  int x )
{
    bool occur = false;
    int i,j = 0;
    for ( i=0; i<DIM; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j<DIM; j++)
        {
            while ( i<k && occur)
            {
                matrix[i][j] == element;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return occur;
}

int main ()
{
    int matrix[DIM][DIM] = {{1,2,3},
                            {4,1,6},
                            {7,8,9}};
    int x = 2;
    int k = 1;
    int elemento = 1;
    if ( check (matrix, element, k , x))
    {
        cout << "l'elemento "<< elemento <<" ricorre "<< k <<" volta/e in "<< x <<" colonna/e";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? What's happening? What's _not_ happening?

Comment: You never set occur. You need to sit and think about your algorithm.

Comment: For an error description like "something is wrong", our solution can't be much more than "fix something" :-) If you want more, first of all give all relevant information to describe your problem as precisely as you can.

Comment: agree with mert, there's never `occur = true`

Comment: `i < k` and `matrix[i][j] == element;` seems incorrect. Also what mert said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the task into smaller chunks. To check if a number occurs k times in x columns, first write a function to check if a number occurs k times in one column. That function will have a single for loop. When you write it, test it to see if you did it correctly. Then put that function in another, very similar for loop and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check(int matrix[M][N], int element, int k, int x)
{
        int c1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
                int c2 = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                        if (matrix[i][j] == element)
                                ++c2;
                }
                if (c2 >= k)
                        ++c1;
        }
        return c1 >= x;
}
```

Optimize it yourself ;)